# Phalcon: Custom Access Control List not setting permissions

Tags: php, acl, phalcon

I am trying to follow an [online tutorial](https://www.udemy.com/phalconphp/learn/v4/overview) in Phalcon PHP, and I'm at the stage where we are creating an ACL, and setting permissions based on the user's role (which is pulled from a session variable).

However, even when a user logs in, and their role changes from `guest` to `user`, the permissions file does not seem to set their permissions correctly, and so they do not get forwarded to their dashboard, but instead drop back to the login screen.

**Permissions.php**

```
use Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher;
use Phalcon\Events\Event;
use Phalcon\Acl;

class Permission extends Phalcon\Mvc\User\Plugin
{
    const GUEST = 'guest';
    const USER = 'user';
    const ADMIN = 'admin';

    protected $_publicResources = [
        'index' => '*',
        'login' => '*'
    ];
    protected $_userResources = [
        'dashboard' => ['*'],
        'logout' => ['*']
    ];
    protected $_adminResources = [
        'admin' => ['*']
    ];

    public function beforeExecuteRoute(Event $event, Dispatcher $dispatcher)
    {
        $role = $this->session->get('role');
        if (!$role) {
            $role = self::GUEST;
        }

        $controller = $dispatcher->getControllerName();
        $action = $dispatcher->getActionName();

        $acl = $this->_getAcl();

        $allowed = $acl->isAllowed($role, $controller, $action);

        if ($allowed != Acl::ALLOW) {
            $this->response->redirect('login/');

            return false;
        }
    }

    protected function _getAcl()
    {
        if (!isset($this->persistent->acl)) {
            $acl = new Acl\Adapter\Memory();
            $acl->setDefaultAction(Acl::DENY);

            $roles = [
                self::GUEST => new Acl\Role(self::GUEST),
                self::USER => new Acl\Role(self::USER),
                self::ADMIN => new Acl\Role(self::ADMIN)
            ];

            foreach ($roles as $role) {
                $acl->addRole($role);
            }

            foreach ($this->_publicResources as $resource => $action) {
                $acl->addResource(new Acl\Resource($resource), $action);
            }

            foreach ($this->_userResources as $resource => $action) {
                $acl->addResource(new Acl\Resource($resource), $action);
            }

            foreach ($this->_adminResources as $resource => $action) {
                $acl->addResource(new Acl\Resource($resource), $action);
            }

            foreach ($roles as $role) {
                foreach ($this->_publicResources as $resource => $action) {
                    $acl->allow($role->getName(), $resource, '*');
                }
            }

            foreach ($this->_userResources as $resource => $actions) {
                foreach ($actions as $action) {
                    $acl->allow(self::USER, $resource, $action);
                    $acl->allow(self::ADMIN, $resource, $action);
                }
            }

            foreach ($this->_adminResources as $resource => $actions) {
                foreach ($actions as $action) {
                    $acl->allow(self::ADMIN, $resource, $action);
                }
            }

            $this->persistent->acl = $acl;
        }

        return $this->persistent->acl;
    }
}
```

And if I `print_r($acl)`, this is what I get:

```
Phalcon\Acl\Adapter\Memory Object
(
    [_eventsManager:protected] => 
    [_defaultAccess:protected] => 0
    [_accessGranted:protected] => 1
    [_activeRole:protected] => user
    [_activeResource:protected] => index
    [_activeAccess:protected] => index
    [_rolesNames:protected] => Array
        (
            [guest] => 1
            [user] => 1
            [admin] => 1
        )

    [_roles:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => Phalcon\Acl\Role Object
                (
                    [_name:protected] => guest
                    [_description:protected] => 
                )

            [1] => Phalcon\Acl\Role Object
                (
                    [_name:protected] => user
                    [_description:protected] => 
                )

            [2] => Phalcon\Acl\Role Object
                (
                    [_name:protected] => admin
                    [_description:protected] => 
                )

        )

    [_resourcesNames:protected] => Array
        (
            [*] => 1
            [index] => 1
            [login] => 1
            [dashboard] => 1
            [logout] => 1
            [admin] => 1
        )

    [_resources:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => Phalcon\Acl\Resource Object
                (
                    [_name:protected] => index
                    [_description:protected] => 
                )

            [1] => Phalcon\Acl\Resource Object
                (
                    [_name:protected] => login
                    [_description:protected] => 
                )

            [2] => Phalcon\Acl\Resource Object
                (
                    [_name:protected] => dashboard
                    [_description:protected] => 
                )

            [3] => Phalcon\Acl\Resource Object
                (
                    [_name:protected] => logout
                    [_description:protected] => 
                )

            [4] => Phalcon\Acl\Resource Object
                (
                    [_name:protected] => admin
                    [_description:protected] => 
                )

        )

    [_access:protected] => Array
        (
            [guest!*!*] => 0
            [user!*!*] => 0
            [admin!*!*] => 0
            [guest!index!*] => 1
            [guest!login!*] => 1
            [user!index!*] => 1
            [user!login!*] => 1
            [admin!index!*] => 1
            [admin!login!*] => 1
        )

    [_roleInherits:protected] => 
    [_accessList:protected] => Array
        (
            [*!*] => 1
            [index!*] => 1
            [login!*] => 1
            [dashboard!*] => 1
            [logout!*] => 1
            [admin!*] => 1
        )

    [_func:protected] => 
    [_noArgumentsDefaultAction:protected] => 1
)
```

Comment: What phalcon version you are using ? My acl has `[user!dashboard!*] => 1` On 3.0.x from your example. Also use role inheritance, you don't need to add userResources to both admin and user. You can just inherit admin role from user role etc.

Comment: Out of curiousity are your controllers in a Namespace? If so you could try this: `protected $_publicResources = ['\Controllers\Index'  => '*',];` -- Im trying to solve this at the moment will let you know if i do!